# What tag should you use to make a custom heading instead of <h1>-<h6>?

Tags: html, css

What tag should you use to make a custom heading? Because according to these sites...

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_headings.asp
W3Schools - Note: Use HTML headings for headings only. Don't use headings to make text BIG or bold.

https://learn.freecodecamp.org/responsive-web-design/applied-accessibility/use-headings-to-show-hierarchical-relationships-of-content
FreeCodeCamp - One final point, each page should always have one (and only one) h1 element, which is the main subject of your content.

Or for example in a case I used up all of the h1 - h6 tags?

Would using p tag with css id be appropriate?

- p Paragraph tag wouldn't make sense
- h# Heading tags, if I change a certain heading tag number with css it would change any tag with the same tag number
- Customising text formatting wouldn't make sense as it's tag name strictly suggests what it's meant to be used for

Comment: you can use `<p>` or a `<span>` and give it a `font-size`

Comment: and you can customize your headings if you give your heading an id

Comment: "I used up all of the h1-h6 headings". That means your document hierarchy is way too complex for consumption. Note that besides h1, you have have any number of h2s, h3s, etc..

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a slight misconception about `<h1>` through `<h6>` (`<hN>`). The numbers `N` do not represent *order* but *hierarchy*. A `<h1>` heading is more important and higher up the hierarchy than a `<h2>`, which itself is higher than `<h3>`, etc. See is like chapters in a textbook.

```
<h1>My Great book</h1>

  <h2>Chapter 1</h2>
    <h3>1.1</h3>
    <h3>1.2</h3>

  <h2>Chapter 2</h2>
    <h3>2.1</h3>
    <h3>2.2</h3>
    <h3>2.3</h3>
    <h3>2.4</h3>

  <h2>Chapter 3</h2>
    <h3>3.1</h3>
    <h3>3.2</h3>
      <h4>3.2.1</h4>
      <h4>3.2.2</h4>
    <h3>3.3</h3>
```

That means you can have as many headings as you wish with one exception (primarily for SEO reasons). You should only have a single `<h1>` per page.

Comment: Google has specifically stated they do not use heading tags for SEO.

Comment: @Rob any quotes for that?

Comment: I think the latest can be found [in one of these videos](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2019/06/a-new-series-on-seo-for-web-developers.html) but it's been stated by Google and widely known for years.

Comment: @Rob `[It has been] widely known for years`: just because *you* know something, don't assume *everyone else* also does. We're always learning :)

Comment: @Rob Wow, no need to be so rude.

Answer (score 0):

You can use heading tags and then use css to style
HTML:

```
<h2>Look at this text</h2>
<h2 class="bigFont">Now look at this text</h2>
```

CSS:

```
.bigFont {
font-size:50px;
} // You can change the size
```

And as mentioned above use only one`<h1>` tag use `<h2>` tags like this

Answer (score 0):

I think one reason is that web crawlers that rank the website use such headings. Which is why it is imperative that your website must have at least 1 `<h1>` tag. Also, it should be noted that the headings from `<h1> - <h6>` must be used in order for better SEO(Search Engine Optimization).

Comment: This isn't true at all and Google has specifically stated they do not use heading tags for SEO.

Comment: There are tons of web crawlers but the majority of search is done with Google and, iirc, Bing doesn't use headings either and it is search you mentioned. I won't bother to look up my sources.

Comment: @Rob Its not just the GoogleBot there are multiple web-crawlers out there although from what I've read GoogleBot uses headers as well, My answer is not based on a single source you can check them if you like:
 https://www.hobo-web.co.uk/headers/
https://www.searchenginejournal.com/how-important-is-h1-tag-for-seo/261547/#close

Comment: Again, Google does not use headings for SEO and they state this everywhere. Your sources are wrong and I suggest you visit Google's YouTube videos where they explicitly state this.

Comment: iirc, it's mentioned in one of these videos: https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2019/06/a-new-series-on-seo-for-web-developers.html